# Supabase: Can I tell Supabase to updgrade the Postgres version?

Tags: supabase

Just re-started my "CI" Supabase project since it had been dormant for a while.

When it came back up, `SELECT version()` shows that it's running Postgres 14.1.
But when I run the same version on my "TST" Supabase project, it shows version 13.3.

I tried restarting the server with the web console, but that had no effect.

I don't actually have a specific problem caused by the version difference - I just don't like the idea of deploying to a higher environment without having tested the release on that version of Postgres.

Is there anyway to align these versions?  (either direction is fine, though I probably prefer to run them both on 14.x.)

Comment: you should contact the team they can upgrade your 13.3 project to 14 for you: https://app.supabase.io/support/new

Answer (score 1):

You can now pause and unpause your project and it would upgrade your Postgres version automatically.

Comment: Do you have any links to documentation or references for this statement?